# k-NN search in HUGE dimensions (~100,000)

Tags: algorithm, knn

Are there any articles about k-NN search problem for really huge amount of dimensions like 10k - 100k?

Most of articles with tests on real-world data operates with 10-50 dims, and a few operates 100-500.

In my case there is ~10^9 points in ~100k feature dimension, and there is no way to effectively reduce number of dimensions.

UPD.:
At the moment we are trying to adapt and implement VP-trees, but it's clear enough that any tree struct on this dimensionality wont work well.

Second approach is LSH, but there may be big troubles with accuracy depending on data distribution.

Comment: I sense an article creation opportunity for user2501091.

Comment: For the benefit of us who've come across this question randomly, could you link to an explanation of LSH please, and maybe other things? Your question reads like gibberish to someone who knows nothing of the topic, which can sometimes be a sign of a bad question. K-nn is thankfully already a tag with some info.

Comment: LSH - Locality-sensitive hashing. It's based on idea that we can project close points to close images.

Comment: LSH - Locality-sensitive hashing. It's based on idea that we can project close points to close images by "hashing" it.
In general it's is probabilistic method in the way that there is only a chance that closest to query point will projected in same bucket with query.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [FLANN](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html) library.

In [this paper](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/papers/flann_visapp09.pdf) you will find a dissertation on how data dimensionality is one of the factors that has a great impact on the nearest neighbor matching performance, and the solutions adopted in FLANN.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using kd-tree for nearest neighbour search? kd-tree deteriorates to almost exhaustive search in higher dimensions.

In higher dimensions, it is usually suggested to use approximate nearest neighbour search. here is the link to the original paper: http://cvs.cs.umd.edu/~mount/Papers/dist.pdf, and if that is a bit too heavy, try this: dimacs.rutgers.edu/Workshops/MiningTutorial/pindyk-slides.ppt‎

There are many factors affecting the choice of decision when it comes to nearest neighbour search.  Whether you need to load the points entirely in primary memory or you could use secondary memory should also govern your decision.